# How to remove list view item in list view android?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my application i have one custom list view. whenever i click the close image list item, the list item layout must be removed with space. i used visibility:gone attribute, the list item layout deleted but the space is visible. I am using listview in scroll view ,,that was also not working....please help me out.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recharge_listitem, null);


        TextView accountnumber = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.accountnumber);
        TextView servicename = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.servicetypname);
        TextView planamount = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.rechargeamount);
      final ImageView close = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.crosse_close_img);
       final LinearLayout layoutrecharge=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rechargelay);
        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                layoutrecharge.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


        accountnumber.setText("Rs."+bpData.get(position).getAccountNumber());
        servicename.setText(bpData.get(position).getServicename());
        planamount.setText(bpData.get(position).getRechargeamount());





        return convertView;
    }

}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"

        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">




    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1e365a">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="PAYMENT"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Your Recharges"
            android:textColor="#1e365a"
            android:textSize="20dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dottedline_view" />


    <ListView

        android:id="@+id/recharge_lv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone">

    </ListView>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.8dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="#1e365a" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Amount to be Paid"
            android:textColor="#1e365a"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Rs.130"
            android:textColor="#1e365a"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ev_b_dob"


            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:hint="Enter coupn code"
            android:inputType="text" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_apply"
            style="@style/payment_button_style"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Apply" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_reload_cash"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pay using Reload Cash"
            android:textColor="#1e365a"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/atmdebit_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#F93249"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="ATM/DEBIT/CREDIT"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/netbankng_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#F93249"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="NET BANKING"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>





</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

please help me.

custom listview item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rechargelay">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/accountnumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="8008505106" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="(" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/servicetypname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Vodafone" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=")" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rechargeamount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RS.30"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/crosse_close_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/close"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where is `close` Button in ListView row?

Comment: close button was in list item of listview

Comment: Show Adapter class code where you are using `close.setOnClickListener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `View.GONE` for View is not right way to remove row from ListView. to remove row remove select row item from Adapter data-source and call notify data change method of adapter to populate changes:

```
close.setTag(position);
close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
           int deletePos=Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
            bpData.remove(deletePos);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
 });
```

Comment: why the  automatic scroll view of list view not working?

Comment: @Kartiki: you are asking how to remove item instead of not automatic scrolling. plz don't add another question

Comment: @Kartiki: my suggestion is create layout again with only single scrollable view and don't place ListView inside ScrollView which is not good according to performance of application or views rendering

Comment: sorry,but i already asked  in the question" the scroll view is not working,..." thats y i asked,,,sorry,,,

Comment: @Kartiki: if you have number of views then separate ScrollView and ListView in separate layouts instead of adding ListView in ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

Set visibility `View.GONE` of `SCROLL VIEW` or other parent of list view....

Comment: close image is the list item of listview. whenever i click close image the layout must be remove with space

Comment: if u take list view than no need of scrollview

Comment: but i have number of widgets after lisview. thats y i used scroll view forthe layout