# How do you delete an item from a list view in android?

Tags: android, list, listview, onitemclicklistener

I'm making a basic To-do List app for android and need some help. I need to learn how to delete items from a list view when its tapped on. I know that you record the taps using the `OnItemClickListener` interface.

Comment: You have to remove the item from the adapter (how to do that depends on the adapter), then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged.  This will make it redraw the list, without the deleted element.

Comment: please, look for a tutorial online instead of publishing a "how to do" question..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove list view item in list view android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28498706/how-to-remove-list-view-item-in-list-view-android)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the data and the adepter you're using.
E.g. if it's http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html then you can use `Adapter.remove()`.
If your data is inside a database, you can use your adapter or the your dbhelper.

Please make sure to provide as much information as possible for your problem, so that it's more clear what your problem is exactly.

Btw. great that you're starting early ;-)